# Methyl anthranilate sulfuric acid - acid base reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

When methyl anthranilate is added to sulfuric acid a white precipitate forms. I am assuming this is an insoluble salt produced in the acid base reaction, where the lone pair on the nitrogen will accept a proton.

My question is, does sulfuric acid lose both protons in the reaction, so that there are 2 ions of the protonated methyl anthranilate with one sulfate ion. Or does it form one protonated methyl anthranilate ion with an HSO4- ion?